query in many to many field order by first related object
in django i want to query in a many to many field that ordered by first related object. that means the queryset have to serach in the objects in the first location of many to many objects then others.
as a simple incorrect sample i want to get objects like this:
queryset = Practitioner.objects.filter(practices__0__city__slug='toronto')
queryset += Practitioner.objects.filter(practices__other__except__0__city__slug='toronto')

Note: practices is a ManyToManyField of Practice model in Practitioner model

A ManyToManyField has no "order", so there does not exist such thing as "first". From a software design point of view that would probably also not make much sense.

by any way we have something like a list of field that related to our object. i have tested that. this list not changes its place of its members

it will indeed likely not change (much) between two queries, since usually the queryplan will even be the same as well as the index. Problems start to occur when you edit indexes. This is one of the reasons they for example designed this package: https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Ordered-ManyToMany.html

the experiment is also (very) flawed. The existance of something does not proof that something always holds. It is not because the database returns items a few times in the same order. Django does not attach an ORDER BY when it queries the ManyToManyField (unless you did an ordering = ... on the Practice, but then the order is thus determined on intrensic aspects of the Practice, not the order when the relation between the two was added), so the database is free to return in the order it likes.

A ManyToManyField has no order. Just like any query without a column to order by, the database can return records in an arbitrary order, and this different each time you query.
If you want to add an order (or something like a "default" practice for example, you can add that to the junction table). Like:
from django.db import models


class City(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # …


class Practice(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Practitioner(models.Model):
    practices = models.ManyToManyField(Practice, through='PractitionerPractice')


class PractitionerPractice(models.Model):
    practitioner = models.ForeignKey(Practitioner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    standard = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('practitioner',),
                condition=models.Q(standard=True),
                name='one_standard',
            )
        ]
The UniqueConstraint [Django-doc] can guarantee at database level each Practitioner only lists one Practice as standard=True one.
In that case we can retrieve the query with:
Practitioner.objects.filter(practices__city__slug='toronto').order_by(
    '-practitionerPractice__standard'
)
